# Faster search String in Mysql Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, string, string-matching

I have a large DB having > 20,000 rows. I have two tables *songs* and *albums*:

table *songs* contains *songid, albumid, songname* and table *albums* contains *albumid, albumname*

Currently when user searches for a song I give results instantly as soon as he starts typing. Just like Google Instant.

What I am using is: Everytime user types I send that *query string* to my backend php file and there I execute that query in my DB like this:

```
SELECT * FROM songs, albums WHERE songs.albumid = albums.albumid AND songs.songname LIKE '%{$query_string}%';
```

But it's very inefficient to use DB queries everytime and also it's not scalable as my DB is growing everyday.

Therefore I want the same feature but faster and efficient and scalable.

Also, I dont want it to be exact pattern matching, for example:

Suppose, if user types "Rihana" instead of "Rihanna" then it should be able to give the results related to **Rihanna**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should find MySQL's `FULLTEXT` search support far faster than your current approach.

I suspect with the kind of speed you'd like from this solution and the support for searching for mis-spelled words that you'd be better off investigating some kind of more featured full text search engine. These include:

- Sphinx Search
- Solr
- ElasticSearch

Comment: Thanks James, I will currently use Full text search with indexing for now. Because I can't install these searching servers currently. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should index table Songs songname column on first n chars, say 6, to get better performance for the query.

Trigger the query search only after n chars have been typed, say 3 (jquery autocomplete has this option, for example)

You may also consider an in-memory DB if performance is truly crucial (sounds like it is) and the amount of data will not consume too much resident memory.

Google, btw, does not use a legacy RDBMS to perform its absurdly fast searches (continually amazed...)

Comment: InnoDB has the option to cache the dataset in the memory for example, so the in-memory engine isn't necessary if InnoDB is used. Also, what does Google's architecture have with your comment about RDBMS? It's the architecture that counts (split the search task across N computers, return the result and UNION it, serving to the client).

Comment: can you please tell me how to index the songname (varchar) on first N characters. ?

Comment: Sure, just shard the search across your N servers, union and serve to the client (not everyone has N servers available, likely the case for OP). Google shards heavily and does not use an RDBMS (performance hit, perhaps?). Good point, for OP InnoDB in-memory may cache may be an excellent choice.

Comment: @Kevindra, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html. "Indexes can be created that use only the leading part of column values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an index prefix length:"

Answer (score 1):

Try [full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

Indexing requires MyISAM tables though.

If you need ACID and full text search, use [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/textsearch.html).

Comment: Thanks Denis this is really helpful for being.